# Creating an Android Service in Clojure

Tags: android, clojure, gen-class

I have a fairly simple app, which I wrote in Clojure and would like to automatically execute one of it's functions periodically.  I am trying to use Android's `AlarmManager` to schedule the task.  This is what I have so far:

Android's Documentation for Reference [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)

```
public class HelloIntentService extends IntentService {

  /**
   * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
   * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
   */
  public HelloIntentService() {
      super("HelloIntentService");
  }

  /**
   * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
   * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
   * stops the service, as appropriate.
   */
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
  }
}
```

My own progress in Clojure:

```
(gen-class
 :name adamdavislee.mpd.Service
 :extends android.app.IntentService
 :exposes-methods {IntentService superIntentService}
 :init init
 :prefix service)

(defn service-init []
  (superIntentService "service")
  [[] "service"])
(defn service-onHandleIntent [this i]
  (toast "hi"))
```

I think I'm misunderstanding something subtle; after evaluating the first sexp, the symbol `adamdavislee.mpd.Service` is unbound, and neither is the symbol `superIntentService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, but only if the project is re-compiled after added the call to `gen-class`.  `gen-class` can only generates classes when a project is being compiled.

```
(gen-class
 :name adamdavislee.mpd.Service
 :extends android.app.IntentService
 :init init
 :state state
 :constructors [[] []]
 :prefix service-)
(defn service-init
  []
  [["NameForThread"]
   "NameForThread"])
(defn service-onHandleIntent
  [this i]
  (toast "service started"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Will make some suggestions based on reading your code (i.e. not sure if these will work)

It looks like you may have an issue with the Java interop. You can see more info [here](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop). It looks like `:prefix` should be a string as well. e.g.

```
(gen-class
 :name adamdavislee.mpd.Service
 :extends android.app.IntentService
 :exposes-methods {IntentService superIntentService}
 :init init
 :prefix "service-")  ;;---> make this a string and append '-'

(defn service-init []
  (.superIntentService "service");;-> update with prepend dot-notation for Java interop
  [[] "service"])                ;;-> not sure what 'service' is doing here 
                                 ;;   perhaps consider an atom
(defn service-onHandleIntent [this i]
  (.toast "hi"))  ;;=> Not sure where this method is coming from, 
                  ;;   but guessing java interop need here as well
```

[This example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class#example-542692d3c026201cdc326fbb) might provide some helpful insights as well. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you; I'm getting closer now, in particular it helped to realize that `superIntentService` was exposed as a method and not a regular symbol.